# Java 6 service using/calling java8 library

Tags: java, gradle, java-8, build.gradle, java-6

Our service still uses Java 6 for compile and run. We need to use a library that is compiled with Java 8. Upon including the dependency in gradle we as expected see errors such as "class file has wrong version"

For android development gradle has something like gradle-retrolambda. Is there any generic gradle client that helps convert this library's bytecode compatible to java 6? or is there any other option other than our service upgrading to java8?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried running your Java 6 compiled code on a Java 8 JRE?  The JRE is supposed to be backwards compatible, so instead of trying to make the JDK 8 compiled library run on an older JRE, it might be a safer bet (and the one that will likely work without much effort) to run your program on Java 8 JRE.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately we are not able to go that route. the program was not successful running on java8 we have other issues and the team is not inclined to do that considering this program is very critical.

Comment: The other possible alternative would be to take the source code of the library, build it on a JDK 1.6 compiler and try to run your app on Java 1.6 JRE.